# How can we find the derivative of a circle if a circle is not a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we consider the equation of a circle, $x^2+y^2=r^2$, then I understand that $dy/dx$ can be computed in the following way via implicit differentiation:
\begin{align}
2x + 2y\frac{dy}{dx} &= 0 \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= -\frac{2x}{2y} = -\frac{x}{y} \, .
\end{align}
Although I feel comfortable deriving this result, I don't really understand how I should interpret it. On an intuitive level, the formula $dy/dx = -x/y$ seems to suggest that the gradient of the tangent to any given point $(x,y)$ is $-x/y$. However, since the curve $x^2+y^2=r^2$ fails the [vertical line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test), it doesn't look like it is even a function. Usually, $dy/dx$ can be thought of as a shorthand for
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h} \, .
$$
However, in this case each $x$-value maps to two $y$-values, and so the limit definition doesn't seem to apply here. So what does $dy/dx$ actually represent in this context?

Comment: Also consider the angle between the tangent line through $(x,y)$ and the radius line from the origin through $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still think of it in terms of the slope of a tangent line, and even in terms of a limit.  However, as you've pointed out, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ isn't a function because it fails the vertical line test.  However, by the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) we can consider $F(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - r^2$, and for any $(x_{0},y_{0})$ where $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\ne 0$ then there exists some neighborhood around the point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ for which we can express $F(x,y) = 0$ as some function $y = f(x)$.  Note that in this case, $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 2y,$$ which is zero whenever $y = 0$, so at the points $(r,0)$ and $(-r,0)$.  On the circle.  Anywhere else we can define the curve by either $$y = \sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}$$ or $$y = -\sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}$$ and these functions are differentiable so long as $y\ne 0$.  To verify that the derivative via the limit definition matches that obtained by implicit differentiation, we can compute as follows for the positive semicircle:
\begin{align}
y' &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{r^{2} - (x+h)^{2}} - \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{r^{2} - (x+h)^{2}} - \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}{h} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{r^{2} - (x+h)^{2}} + \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}{\sqrt{r^{2} - (x+h)^{2}} + \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r^{2} - (x+h)^{2} - r^{2} - x^{2}}{h(\sqrt{r^{2} - (x+h)^{2}} + \sqrt{r^2 - x^2})}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-2xh -h^{2}}{h(\sqrt{r^{2} - (x+h)^{2}} + \sqrt{r^2 - x^2})}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-2x - h}{\sqrt{r^{2} - (x+h)^{2}} + \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}\\
&=-\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}}\\
&=-\frac{x}{y}.
\end{align}
Where the last equality comes from the equation $y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}.$  We could do the same for the negative semicircle.

Answer (score 3):

While each $x\in(-r,\,r)$ is compatible with two choices of $y$, continuous motion along the circumference well-defines the choice of $y$ at each point, giving a local $y$-as-a-function-of-$x$ behaviour wherever $dy/dx$ is finite and nonzero (i.e. $x,\,y$ are both nonzero), which happens at all but four of the circumference's points.

This local behaviour is more easily described in terms of the polar angle $\theta$, and since $x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta$, by the chain rule $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}=\frac{x}{-y}=-\cot\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

The curve is indeed not the graph of a function. At any point $(x,y)$ on the curve, if an open disk about that point is small enough, then that portion of the curve that is within that neighborhood is the graph of a function, and the slope of the tangent line to the graph of that function is $-x/y.$

Derivatives are *local*, that is the slope of a curve at a point is determined by the behavior of that curve within a small open neighborhood of the point, no matter how small it is.

Also, the concept of a tangent line to a curve is not limited to curves that are the graph of a function, so

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for this answer. In the past, I have seen the notion of tangent line be extended. For example, $y=x^{1/3}$ has a vertical slope at $x=0$, even though the derivative does not exist at this point. However, I'm not sure what the formal definition of 'tangent' is in this context. Is it possible if you could elaborate on this?